# How do I kill a server in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I run a node server via `node server.js`

In PowerShell (sans ISE) I can hit `CTRL` + `C` or `CTRL` + `BREAK` twice to stop the server. However, running the same shortcut in ISE will make it hang. It says "stopping" in the bar across the bottom (I imagine this would be referred to as the status bar) but never actually stops.

Is there a shortcut that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is to create a new powershell tab, then kill the server from the new tab (using `stop-process` for instance). Then switch back to the old tab and (after a possible few second delay) the server will have been terminated. Once you have the command to terminate the server in the command line history of the second PS tab, it will be a little quicker to subsequently kill the server.

Another way I handle this if I have a PS script (vs an external program) that has hung is to create a new powershell tab (ctrl-T), then click the old tab, then click the X on the old tab. Unfortunately you'll have to reopen any files you were editing.